# Css module with react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm building a React website, to enable css modules styles I eject my project I used

```
npm run eject
```

And i added extra configurations in the webpack.config.dev.js and webpack.config.prod.js files, the problem is that I was using a component call *react-big-calendar* (https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar), and in that module I have to import a css file. The problem is that when I enable the module features it doesn't apply the css styles to the calendar, It used to look like: [image]

And now it looks like this:

[image]

What can I do in order to apply classes from the big-calendar css file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now you don't have to eject your project and add extra config to webpack.config to enable css modules.
Now whenever you want to use css modules, just name the file [name].module.css and that's it. This will solve your problem with the components which are not using css modules.

Let me know if it works for you